# Is here any logical error?

Tags: c, while-loop

```
void mul()   
{  
    int x,y,sum = 0;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    scanf("%d",&y);
    while (x != 0){
        if (x%2 != 0)
            sum = sum + y; 
        x = x/2;
        y = 2*y;
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
}

int main()   
{   
    char c;
    printf("Enter two numbers and y to exit");
    //mul();
    scanf("%c",&c);
    while (c != 'y'){
        mul();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On running this program it is not getting exit on giving input 'y'. Why?

Comment: You will run into the problem that `scanf()` reading integers will leave a newline behind for the `scanf()` reading a character to process. You should debug by printing the data you read, so you know whether the program is getting what you think it is getting as input.  You should also test the return value from `scanf()`; you will get odd behaviour if you have an early EOF, or non-numeric data when you expect numeric data.

Answer (score 2):

You are not scanning in the `while` loop. Do this:

```
char c = 'n';
while (c != 'y')
{
    printf("Enter two numbers and y to exit");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    mul();
}
```

Just to point out something extra, when you enter a character like `y` or `n` and hit the ENTER key, a character (which you entered) and a character (which is the enter keystroke - the newline character) are placed in the input buffer.The first character gets consumed by the `scanf` but the newline remains in the input buffer.

Solution is to consume the extra newline by using:

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
       ^<------------Note the space
```

Comment: (Or more to the point; he's not modifying `c` in the while loop.)

Comment: @Acme: and initialize `char c` to a dummy value beforehand

Comment: `mul()` should be before `scanf()`

Comment: @Enigma There's a `scanf("%c", &c);` before the loop.

Comment: @user2771151 - Do select the answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Better you do this way

```
do{
    scanf("%c",&c);
    mul();
}while (c != 'y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code or just add "static int main" in your code.

```
 int Main() 
{
   char c;
   printf("Enter y to exit");
   scanf("%c",&c);
   while (c != 'y')
     {
        mul();
      } return 0;   }

void mul()   {  
printf("Enter two numbers");  
int x,y,sum = 0;  
scanf("%d",&x);  
scanf("%d",&y);   ................    }
```

Comment: `public static int main` is not C.

Comment: @YuHao Thanks buddy I didn't notice it.